# MAVROS PX4 Error Failed to Import Packaging

Tags: ros, mavlink, px4, ros-melodic, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial: https://dev.px4.io/v1.9.0/en/ros/

I've run the build scripts: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PX4/Devguide/v1.9.0/build_scripts/ubuntu_sim_ros_melodic.sh

I've built my catkin workspace using catkin build at ~/catkin_ws , and the command `roslaunch mavros px4.launch fcu_url:="udp://:14540@127.0.0.1:14557"` runs with no issues.

I've also downloaded the firmware in the directory ~/src/Firmware, but I run into issues when I run the command

> DONT_RUN=1 make px4_sitl_default gazebo

At first I got the error `ImportError: No module named 'em', Error`, but it went away after running `pip3 install empy`

Now I am getting the error

```
Failed to import packaging: No module named 'packaging'
You may need to install it using:
pip3 install --user packaging
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Makefile:198: recipe for target 'px4_sitl_default' failed
make: *** [px4_sitl_default] Error 1
```

The errors start at:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "gazebo_vision_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_uuv_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_lidar_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_geotagged_images_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_controller_interface" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "sensor_msgs" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_sonar_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_opticalflow_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "std_msgs" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_imu_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_opticalflow_mockup_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "mav_msgs" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "nav_msgs" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_wind_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "physics_msgs" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_gimbal_controller_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_mavlink_interface" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_motor_model" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_catapult_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_multirotor_base_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_magnetometer_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_usv_dynamics_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_barometer_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_parachute_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_gst_camera_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_irlock_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_gps_plugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "gazebo_video_stream_widget" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
    linked by target "LiftDragPlugin" in directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo
```

Please help if you can!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349159/mavros-px4-error-failed-to-import-packaging/) by [quadman](https://answers.ros.org/users/53463/quadman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-11**:
Quick comment: Python 3 is not mentioned anywhere in the build script you link. I have no experience with mavros, but ROS Melodic does not support Python 3.

You seem to be using Python 3 (and worked around one issue by installing `empy` with `pip3`).

You may want to check the default Python interpreter on your system. Only Python 2 is officially supported in ROS Melodic. ROS Noetic will be the first ROS version to support Python 3 completely.

**Comment by [quadman](https://answers.ros.org/users/53463/quadman/) on 2020-04-11**:
When I run python -V I get 2.7, but I used python 3 to install that package since I have both on my machine.

**Comment by [quadman](https://answers.ros.org/users/53463/quadman/) on 2020-04-11**:
I think you may be on to something, although python 2.7 is my default, I am getting these errors:

[6/723] Generating serial_params.c
FAILED: generated_params/serial_params.c
cd /home/christopher/src/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default/src/lib/parameters && /usr/bin/cmake -E make_directory /home/christopher/src/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default/generated_params && /usr/bin**/python3**

It's trying to use python3 for some reason.

**Comment by [quadman](https://answers.ros.org/users/53463/quadman/) on 2020-04-11**:
I fixed those gstream errors by installing gstream using: `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This question seems to provide a solution:](https://answers.ros.org/question/295012/how-can-i-install-ros-melodic-with-python3/)

---

Originally posted by [quadman](https://answers.ros.org/users/53463/quadman/) with karma: 41 on 2020-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0